# C++: How to specify array length with a static constant variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, stdarray

I want to declare the length of an *array member variable* using a *constant static variable of the class*. If I do:

```
// A.h
#include <array>
using namespace std;
class A {
      array<int,LENGTH> internalArray;
public:
      const static int LENGTH;
};

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
constexpr int A::LENGTH{10};
```

There is the error in A.h: "*'LENGTH' was not declared in this scope*", when declaring internalArray.

I find it weird because how come a class member variable, i.e. LENGTH, is out of scope inside the class? The only workaround I found was to move the initialization from A.cpp to A.h:

```
// A.h
#include <array>
using namespace std;
constexpr int LENGTH{10};
class A {
      array<int,LENGTH> internalArray;
public:
      const static int LENGTH;
};
```

But as I understand, first these are two different variables: the global namespace scope LENGTH and the class scope LENGTH. Also, declaring a variable in .h (outside class A) will create an independent LENGTH object in every translation unit where the header is included.

Is there a way to specify the length of the array with a static class-scoped variable?

Comment: _how come a class member variable <...> is out of scope inside the class_ Because the compiler reads the files top-down. If some name is undeclared at the point it sees it - error is raised. And, clearly, `LENGTH` is below first usage of it.

Comment: You probably need the value of `LENGTH` defined in the header (and above the definition of the array); without it, the size of an instance of `A` is unavailable to anyone except `A.cpp`, which makes it impossible for anyone else to instantiate your class (how do they know how much memory to reserve for an instance otherwise?). Have you tried defining it per [the guidelines here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832836/defining-static-const-variable-in-c)? That's for C-style arrays, but it's the same idea; you need to have a defined value for `LENGTH` to use it as a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius you are right I had to put the declaration of LENGTH first.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow you were right I had to put the declaration of LENGTH first.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the info, I have to finish coding something and I'll take a look at your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <array>

class A {
 public:
  static const size_t LENGTH = 12;
 private:
  std::array<int,LENGTH> internalArray;
};

int main(){
  A a;
}
```

You can declare the value of `LENGTH` right in your class header, no need to have it be a separate global variable or for it to live in the cpp file.

Use the `size_t` type, since that is what the `std::array` template expects.

If that public/private arrangement is bad for you, know that you can include multiple public/private indicators in the class header.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard, this does the trick. I can modify the public/private arrangement without problem, btw. Thanks again.